# How to target Fire Tv devices in android studio?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, television, amazon-fire-tv

i created an app for fire tv, i tested it on my firetv it works but won't show up on amazon store on Fire Tv. After contacting them they send me an email.
*
Thank you for contacting us. Your app didn't target any Fire TV devices.

When you submit your APK to the Appstore, the attributes in your app manifest determine what devices your app can be installed on. Incompatibilities between your manifest and a device’s capabilities will prevent the APK file from being supported on that device.*

Please let me know how do I target Fire Tv.

I have mentioned my manifest file below.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.journaldev.awazent"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
}
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}
```

I selected Fire Tv while submitting the app but it needs the code in Manifest.

Answer (score 0):

In the manifest you need to include

`<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false" />`

to allow the app to target a TV (or other non-touchscreen) device. Without that, it will default to assuming a touchscreen is required (ruling out TV)

See [Device Filtering](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/app-submission/device-filtering-and-compatibility.html#device_filtering_for_tv_apps) for other specifics